# image download using angular js net work error

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to download image using below code. But file showed as download with error
(Failed - Network error)

I am using below code

```
    $scope.downloadDocument = function (doc) {
        $http({
            method: "GET",
            url: appConfig.apiUrl + "/downloadDoc/" + $scope.array.nic + "/" + doc.fileName
        }).then(function (response) {
            console.log(response);
            $scope.downloadedImage = response.data;
            var a = document.createElement("a"); //Create <a>
            a.href = "data:image/jpge;base64," + response.data; //Image Base64 Goes here
            console.log(a);
            a.download = doc.fileName; //File name Here
            a.click(); //Downloaded file
        }, function (response) {
            $log.log(response);
        });

    }
```

My response

[image]

When I click download button. It shows as download with error. Check below image

[image]

How i do this correctly. please help

Comment: I recommend to use https://www.base64-image.de/ to create `base64` from your image and set in your `<a>` tag to determine you have valid base64 or not

Answer (score 0):

You need to add ***responseType:'blob'***  your request,
also I prefer use object url (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/createObjectURL) for downloading files

```
function downloadBlob(blob, name) {
      const data = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);

      const link = document.createElement('a');
      link.href = data;
      link.target = '_self';
      link.download = name;

      link.dispatchEvent(
        new MouseEvent('click', {
          bubbles: true,
          cancelable: true,
          view: window
        })
      );

      setTimeout(() => {
        window.URL.revokeObjectURL(data);
        link.remove();
      }, 100);
  }


$scope.downloadDocument = function (doc) {
    $http({
        method: "GET",
        url: appConfig.apiUrl + "/downloadDoc/" + $scope.array.nic + "/" + doc.fileName,
        responseType: 'blob'
    }).then(function (response) {
        console.log(response);
        downloadBlob(new Blob([response.data]), doc.fileName);
    }, function (response) {
        $log.log(response);
    });

}
```

Comment: i'm not tested!! you may faced some error